confirmation using the right tests
Users were asked to pick the AGE GROUP, GENDER and EDUCATIONAL LEVEL each from 3 provided options. I want to check the connection between each of these variables and answers to the question where user also were supposed to pick one of the three answers. For now I decided to go for pearson's ChiSquared Independence Test or Fishers Test (because one of the assumptions for Pearsons is to have at least 5 answers in each instance)
the same as in first one, but I want to connect it with a question where users were supposed to rate something on 1-9 scale. Here I decided for ANOVA or Kruskal-wilis (when the normality assumption is not met)
The research question is as follows, how do specific emojis vary in perception and interpretation across different genders, age groups and educational levels and to what extent do those variables influence or moderate these interpretations?
am i following the right approach?

Hi. You could use ordinal regression to model the issue. Note that there are already many threads about it on this website, in case you have some questions about it.
